# Does TLS prevents replay attacks if the originator is compromised / intentionally wants to cheat

Tags: security, ssl, networking, tcp

Background: I'm working on a mobile application (online chat) that use persistent TCP connections to a backend server. In the previous version, we used a well-known encryption scheme to protect the payload and sign using a shared secret key. This provided sufficient protection against data tampering and reverse engineering. But the traffic was still susceptible to replay attacks: someone can capture the network traffic and replay it and server would accept the requests since it had no idea whether it was real or replayed. To counter this, **we introduced timestamps and nonces which provided protection against replay attacks**.

All well and good. A decision was later made to **use TLS (Transport Layer Security) to protect all communication** between clients and servers. TLS was implemented and to provide an extra layer of protection against Man-in-the-Middle attacks, we pinned the public certificate of the server on clients.

Which brings me to the question: **is it still necessary to use custom encryption and guard against replay attacks since TLS already provides protection against these**? In my research, I found that TLS provides protection during transmission i.e. prevents man in the middle but **what if the originator itself wants to cheat the system and modify payload or replay traffic**? Does TLS protect against an intentional cheater trying to somehow intercept the traffic in the network layer of their OS? My understanding was that TLS provides end-to-end encryption but I have a suspicion that TLS traffic could, in fact, be replayed if the originator wishes to.

I'm also aware of memory-based attacks where the attacker would modify the memory on the device this modifying payload (may be even record and replay.) But even our custom encryption + replay guard won't protect against these.

From: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Benefits

"TLS also provides two additional benefits that are commonly overlooked; integrity guarantees and replay prevention. A TLS stream of communication contains built-in controls to prevent tampering with any portion of the encrypted data. In addition, controls are also built-in to prevent a captured stream of TLS data from being replayed at a later time.

It should be noted that TLS provides the above guarantees to data during transmission. TLS does not offer any of these security benefits to data that is at rest. Therefore appropriate security controls must be added to protect data while at rest within the application or within data stores."

Comment: ' My understanding was that TLS provides end-to-end encryption but I have a suspicion that TLS traffic could, in fact, be replayed if the originator wishes to.' No. The originator can reply the original plaintext transaction, over a new TLS session with new key material, but he can't replay the original TLS session. Whether the plaintext replay is successful and/or does anything depends on the server, idempotence, etc.

Comment: Do you really think you can do better than Signal and the Signal Protocol?

Comment: @zaph No. Signal is great. This is, however, a legacy corporate application so deprecating it in favor of signal isn't an option.

Answer (score 6):

TLS only protects the transport and thus it provides protection against modifying or replaying of the *encrypted* data only. It does not protect against any kind of modifications or replaying of the data before the encryption or after decryption. Sending the same data again over a TLS connection is actually perfectly valid.

But, the nonce and timestamp you use to detect replay do not protect against modification or replaying too. The sender can still use the same data but "protect" these with the new nonce and the new timestamp. It is simply not possible to protect against this kind of client based attacks as long as the attacker is able to modify the client code which is usually the case if the client runs on a system owned by the attacker like in case of a smartphone game where the owner of the smartphone likes to cheat.